# Functional programming for Array.map()

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I've been reading recently about [Functional Programming](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/05/04/functional-programming-in-javascript-map-filter-reduce/) and [Immutable Objects](https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/) in Javascript. What is the functional programming way of using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method?

Say I want to double values in an array. I can do:

```
var arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
arr1.map(function(el){
    el.a = el.a*2;
    return el;
});

// arr1 => [{a: 2}, {a: 4}, {a: 6}]
```

But this seems to break the rules of functional porgramming and immutability the callback will modify directly elements of the array. Is the following the 'correct' way to do this?

```
var arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
var arr2 = angular.copy(arr1);

var arr2 = angular.copy(arr1).map(function(el){
  el.a = el.a*2;
  return el;
});

arr1 = arr2;

// arr1 => [{a: 2}, {a: 4}, {a: 6}]
```

Or am I simply overthinking this? Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2oymhn6/1/).

Comment: `But this seems to break the rules of functional porgramming and immutability. ` How? since `map` will not modify the existing array, it will return a new one.

Comment: @gurvinder372  map itself won't modify, but -> `el.a = el.a * 2` will.

Comment: you should do like `var arr2 = arr1.map(el => el*2);`

Comment: If you don't want `arr1` to be mutated, then simply `return el.a*2;` and taking output in `arr2` will do the job.

Comment: @redu  Do you mean `arr2 = arr1.map(el => {a:el.a*2})`

Comment: @gurvinder372 functional programming says callbacks shouldn't mutate values though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which does not mutate the input object, by simple return something and not assigning something to an element of data.

```js
var arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}],
    arr2 = arr1.map(function (el) {
        return  el.a * 2;
    });

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```

Return an array with new objects

```js
var arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}],
    arr2 = arr1.map(function (el) {
        return  { a: el.a * 2 };
    });

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: I suppose it should map back to the item objects with doubled a properties.

Comment: I think the OP made things slightly confusing here, as he said the results were `// arr1 => [2, 4, 6]` , when in fact there `[{a:2},{a:4},{a:6}]`, easy change of course just wrap in a new object literal.

Comment: it is a bit unclear, but for changing values inside of the array's objects, i would take forEach and not map and assign the new value in situ.

Comment: @Keith Correct, should be [{a: 2}, {a: 4}, {a: 6}]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a pure function that does not mutate its arguments. So if you want objects with the doubled values, you have to create new objects:

```js
 var arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
 console.log(arr1);
 var arr2 = arr1.map(function(el) {
    return {a: el.a*2};
 });
 console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring assignment would make this pretty nice. Either way tho, you have to make a new object otherwise objects in arr1 will be modified.

```js
let arr1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
let arr2 = arr1.map(({a}) => ({a: a * 2}))

console.log(arr1); // [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
console.log(arr2); // [{a: 2}, {a: 4}, {a: 6}]
```